# College Student Out-Of-State License and Registration

Tags: license-plates

I will be attending college in Virginia and I live in Colorado. I will be taking my vehicle with me. Will I have to get a Virginia's drivers license and register my car in Virginia?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're changing your official residence, no. You will need to make sure you're still meeting all of Colorado's requirements (inspections, registration fees, insurance requirements, etc.)